# jQuery .html() not setting content correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Here is the example I prepared to tell about the problem easier.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVpYXm

As you can see the initial `<html>` is set to display a text:

> "This is the old html!"

It sets the whole content to the data in the variable `myHtml`. however here is what I notice:

the style is not carried from the `<body>` element. Moreover, the `<body>` element is somehow not created at all!

Here is the sring `myHtml`, tidied up to display as an html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title Here</title>
<link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
</head>
<body style='background-color: red'>
<div>Div!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've realized that when link element is removed, everything works fine. Try it, see it yourself.

Stuck with this issue for the last few hours. Looking for a result.

Here is the full code:

page html:

```
<html>
  This is the old html!
</html>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
  var myHtml = "<html><head><title>Title Here</title><link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/></head><body style='background-color: red'><div>Div!</div></body></html>"
  $("html").html(myHtml);
})
```

The main purpose of this question is to understand the reason of this behavior as well as finding the best solution.

Comment: Rather than the brute-force approach of setting the entire HTML section, just change small pieces as needed (such as setting the HTML and style of the `div` only).

Comment: right now I'm looking for an answer to the specific case I described above. Otherwise I change partsi normally.

Comment: @JaromandaX did you check the codepen link?

Comment: Post a *complete* code example in your question please. If codepen is ever inaccessible then your question loses all value without a complete example. That said, what do you expect `href='style.css'` to do in your example? How is codepen going to load that stylesheet?

Comment: complete code is posted. refresh and check please.

Comment: @j08691 link does nothing, it breaks the code. That's the whole intention of it.

Comment: @j08691 that's why my question exits in the first place.

Comment: @JaromandaX I've explained the desired behavior. Tell me which part you don't understand and I'll clear it up for you.

Comment: Assuming this did what you want you'd have `<html><html>...</html></html>` because you're adding to `<html>` **not** replacing.

Comment: How am I replacing it @Popnoodles? I'm setting the html directly via `.html()`

Comment: "because you're adding to **not** replacing"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace the entire HTML node using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236360/how-do-i-replace-the-entire-html-node-using-jquery) - Your answer is there http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVpYXm

Comment: @Popnoodles do you want to provide a working example? Feel free to edit my codepen. I'm not sure I get what you mean. And no, my question is def. not a duplicate of what you've posted as my problem depends on the weird issue about the link element I've explained in the thread question.

Comment: I did provide a working example using the answer in that duplicate. Here it is again http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVpYXm

Comment: @JaromandaX no sarcasm here - I'm direct about everything

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that, when you use jQuery's `html(val)`, it does something like this:

```js
html: function(value) {
  /* ... */
  // See if we can take a shortcut and just use innerHTML
  if ( typeof value === "string" && !rnoInnerhtml.test( value ) && /* ... */) {
    /* ... */ elem.innerHTML = value; /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

That is, it checks the string with the regex `rnoInnerhtml`, which is

```
rnoInnerhtml = /<(?:script|style|link)/i
```

Therefore, presumably to avoid inserting stylesheets, jQuery avoids `innerHTML` and does complicated things with `domManip`.

I recommend using native `innerHTML`:

```
$("html").prop('innerHTML', myHtml);
```

```js
var myHtml = "<head><title>Title Here</title><link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/></head><body style='background-color: red'><div>Div!</div></body>"
$("html").prop('innerHTML', myHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
This is the old html!
```

Or with vanilla-js:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

```js
var myHtml = "<head><title>Title Here</title><link href='style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/></head><body style='background-color: red'><div>Div!</div></body>"
document.documentElement.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

```html
This is the old html!
```

Comment: does this do the same? (innerHtml)

Comment: Why and who is downvoting this? Is there any problem with this?

Comment: @Mia Yes, jQuery's `html` should behave as a getter or setter of `innerHTML`. I guess I'm being downvoted by [jQuery fans which don't like vanilla-js](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhaO.gif).

Comment: lol, okay, thanks. You got my vote up. However I want to understand what the problem is in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're appending an `html` element inside the root `html` element, which is undefined behavior and cannot be rendered reliably by the browser. Strip the opening and closing `<html>` and `</html>` tags from your `myHtml` string and it works!

[Working demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVjbaX)

```
$(function() {
  var myHtml = "<head><title>Title Here</title></head><body style='background-color: red; '><div>Div!</div></body>"
  $('html').html(myHtml);
})
```

Alternatively, you could keep the tags and write directly to the `document` object instead, which opens a new stream and overwrites the previous document.

```
// ...
document.write(myHtml);
```

Comment: Ok fair enough. I tried it and that didn't work! Must have had a typo.

Comment: No worries, just  don't be too quick to downvote next time. :)

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood thanks for providing an answer --- I need the html tags in my current case. I'm loading full pages via ajax in the production version, this is just an oversimplified example.

Comment: also if you remove the link element it starts working. The main purpose of the question for me is to understand the reason of this behavior as well as finding the best answer

Comment: The reason of the behaviour was given in this answer. You're creating invalid HTML. Removing the HTML tags is the solution.

Comment: @Mia I would not recomment to use AJAX in that way (see [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6189100/should-i-load-an-entire-html-page-with-ajax)) but in any case, you'd have to write to the document object instead. The problem is that an `html` inside an `html` causes undefined behavior. Browsers could render such a document however they want, therefore it can't be reasoned with.

Comment: @Mia AJAX is usually reserved to dynamically load *parts* of a document. I could understand the choice If you're going for the SPA feel (you want to load a different document without changing the URL). Otherwise you may be overcomplicating things.

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood almost exactly my case. I just want to replace my whole html document without changing the url.

Comment: thank you very much @GuybrushThreepwood - but this is a jquery specific question (as I tried to make it clear in the title). I would love to have a jquery answer to the issue.

Comment: I don't see why. jQuery *is* JavaScript and this is a one-line solution. Anyway, as you wish.